# How to use apache ..htaccess in lightspeed web server

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I did some .htaccess code to make PHP API route.

It's working in apache ( local server )

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#What does this mean??
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ quizAPI.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But when I moved mine code to server it's not working because it not an apache.
I am trying to make API URL Like this :

```
example.com/users/get/
```

Comment: Is this page helpful? https://openlitespeed.org/kb/migrate-apache-rewrite-rules-to-openlitespeed/

Comment: One possible solution is to use the configuration file for the web server you are using on the server (e.g. Nginx or IIS) to set up URL rewriting rules.

Comment: If you are moving your code to a server that is not using Apache as the web server, you may need to use a different configuration file or method to achieve the same rewrite behavior.

Comment: "it's not working" - What is happening specifically? Are you getting an error? (Server error? Error with your script?)

Comment: It's 404 error always but now is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #What does this mean??
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ quizAPI.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

Not quite sure of the difference between Apache and LiteSpeed in this respect (perhaps a difference in how the request is mapped to the filesystem?), however, this is only working on Apache arguably by "chance". The reason being, when you request `/users/get/` the above rewrites as follows:

1. Request `/user/get/`
2. Rewrite (1st pass) to `quizAPI.php?url=user/get/`
3. Rewrite process then starts over (due to the `L` flag)
4. Rewrite (2nd pass) to `quizAPI.php?url=quizAPI.php&url=user/get/` (due to the `QSA` flag)
5. Rewrite process then starts over (due to the `L` flag)
6. Rewrite (3rd pass) to `quizAPI.php?url=quizAPI.php&url=user/get/` (again)
7. Rewriting process stops since the URL has passed through unchanged.

This still "works" (on Apache) since the `url` parameter (as read by your PHP script) is still `user/get/` (the 2nd instance of the `url` param overwrites the first in the `$_GET` array). And there is no rewrite-loop. LiteSpeed, however, might be triggering another pass by the rewrite engine (causing a "loop").

However, we need to prevent that second pass by the rewrite engine (on Apache as well) and I would expect this would resolve the issue on LiteSpeed as well.

One way is to prevent the rewrite from occurring when `quizAPI.php` is requested. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/quizAPI\.php$
RewriteRule (.+) quizAPI.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, this still rewrites all static assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) to your script (which I'm assuming must "OK", since it "works" on Apache), but this might need further modification in the future.

Alternatively, if your URLs that you pass to `quizAPI.php` don't contain dots (that otherwise delimit file-extensions) then it would be simpler to only match URLs that don't contain dots instead (which avoids the need for the preceding *condition*). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ quizAPI.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this naturally avoids rewriting requests for your static assets as well.